# Multiple Join count doesnt get 0

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I've been trying to get data with joins. But problem is result doesn't has records which are has no data in second or third table.
Here is the query;

```
SELECT AUDIT_CONFIG.TITLE,AUDIT_CONFIG.AUDITOR_POOL,AUDIT_CONFIG.FREQUENCE,
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(AUDIT_CONFIG.START_DATE,'yyyymmdd'),'dd/mm/yyyy') AS "START", 
AUDIT_CONFIG.AUDIT_ID, TO_CHAR(MAX(AUDIT_DATES.AUDIT_DATE), 'dd/mm/yyyy') AS "FINISH", 
TRUNC(MAX(AUDIT_DATES.AUDIT_DATE) - SYSDATE) DAY_TO,
(SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT UNIQ_ID) FROM SENDED_AUDIT) AS SCHEDULED,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUDIT_RESULTS WHERE PASSORFAIL='P') AS PASS,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUDIT_RESULTS WHERE PASSORFAIL='F') AS FAIL

FROM AUDIT_CONFIG                                      
RIGHT JOIN AUDIT_DATES ON AUDIT_DATES.AUDIT_ID = AUDIT_CONFIG.AUDIT_ID 
RIGHT JOIN SENDED_AUDIT ON SENDED_AUDIT.AUDIT_ID=AUDIT_CONFIG.AUDIT_ID
RIGHT JOIN AUDIT_RESULTS ON AUDIT_RESULTS.AUDIT_ID=AUDIT_CONFIG.AUDIT_ID

GROUP BY AUDIT_CONFIG.TITLE, AUDIT_CONFIG.AUDITOR_POOL, AUDIT_CONFIG.FREQUENCE, 
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(AUDIT_CONFIG.START_DATE, 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd/mm/yyyy'), AUDIT_CONFIG.AUDIT_ID;
```

And here is a image for understanding the problem; (my query returns just first row)

[image: what i want]

So any advice for getting 0 rows? Thanks in advance..

**EDİT For Thorsten Kettner:** 
Solved now :) thank you for your help and time

Comment: So you are getting the second row in output but you want the count as `0`?

Comment: On a sidenote: You are using `to_date(audit_config.start_date, 'yyyymmdd')`. So you expect `start_date` to be a string formatted `'yyyymmdd'`. Why don't you store it as a date in the first place?

Comment: @Utsav No my result is only first row. I drawed second one for explain what i want.

Comment: Then you should consider changing all `right join` to `left join`, as you need data from `AUDIT_CONFIG` even when there is no match.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner I know it looks like a DATE but it is not. For a reason i store that data as varchar2 in that table. Like-> 20170529 :) So thats why i convert it.

Comment: @Utsav Actually i tryed it. When i do that; result has 2 row yes but second row has 17-26-4 like first. It should be 0-0-0 because there is no data in that tables with audit_id=2.

Comment: That is because you are hardcoding the column. `(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AUDIT_RESULTS WHERE PASSORFAIL='F')` will give same output for all rows. Give sample relevant data for all tables so we can think of  a way for you to get the output. Or better, create all 3 tables in dbfiddle.uk

Comment: @Utsav Oh you are right. Now i added `where` statement to all that lines and now it works as i want. Thank you so much for help and time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks overly complicated

- To start with: Few people use right outer joins for we find them less intuitive than left outer joins. It even seems you were confused with the joins and really wanted left joins instad.
- Another thing is the count subqueries that are not related to the records in the main query. I don't think this is on purpose, is it?
- Then you join `sended_audit` and `audit_results` - the same tables you are using in the count subqueries, but you don't use these joined records in your query.

I guess you want:

```
select 
  ac.title,
  ac.auditor_pool,
  ac.frequence,
  to_char(to_date(ac.start_date, 'yyyymmdd'), 'dd/mm/yyyy') as "start", 
  ac.audit_id,
  to_char(ad.max_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy') as "finish", 
  trunc(ad.max_date - sysdate) as day_to,
  sa.scheduled,
  nvl(ar.pass, 0) as pass,
  nvl(ar.fail, 0) as fail
from audit_config ac
left join
(
  select audit_id, max(audit_date) as max_date
  from audit_dates
  group by audit_id
) ad on ad.audit_id = ac.audit_id
left join
(
  select audit_id, count(distinct uniq_id) as scheduled
  from sended_audit
  group by audit_id
) sa on sa.audit_id = ac.audit_id
left join
(
  select 
    audit_id, 
    count(case when passorfail = 'p' then 1 end) as pass,
    count(case when passorfail = 'f' then 1 end) as fail
  from audit_results
  group by audit_id
) ar on ar.audit_id = ac.audit_id;
```

Comment: This is clear and instructive solution for the problem. Thank you so much :)

Comment: Can i ask one more question? I decided to add a new join to query but there is an error on aa.audit_id=ac.audit_id it doesn't accept aa.audit_id somehow. I dont understand, do you have any advice? (Yes i did add aa.areas on top of the query -after select) here is what i added;

`left join
(
   select wm_concat(audit_area) from auditconfg_areas
   group by audit_id
) aa on aa.audit_id=ac.audit_id`

Comment: You forgot to put `audit_id` in the select clause: `select audit_id, wm_concat(audit_area) ...`.

Comment: No i added it i think. I've edited my post for you can you check please?

Comment: @Kettner Oh i found the problem now and solved it. Thank you so much again :)